# What does the to_char function do?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Here's the complete code:

```
SELECT last_name, hire_name, To_char(hired_date, 'DAY') "Day"
from employees
order by to_char(hire_date -1,'d')
```

I want to understand this part of the code.

```
 to_char (hire_date -1, 'd')
```

Can someone explain me how does the `to_char` function work?

Comment: This is oracle, in mysql it is DATE_FORMAT

Comment: Is it not possible for you to run and see what is the output? By the way, in Oracle it'll give you the day of the week. Like MONDAY if you run it today with SYSDATE.

Comment: i try to run code and the purpose of this code is to order the day to monday, tuesday, etc. and i notice that -1 helps to order the day depends on the number you add or minus, and if i will change to_char (hire_date +20, 'd') [like that] same result how come the result is the same?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is oracle. 
What happens ( as far as i get it) is that it takes the day of a date minus one day. Hope this helps you understand it.

```
 So, 
 TO_Char(hired_date -1, day) 
 T0_Char  = method name
 hired_date = orginional date
 -1 = orignional date minus 1 day
 day = return the the day ( Sunday , Monday wensday)
```

Comment: so sunday =1 monday =2 tuesday =3 etc. is the default order of day in oracle.

Comment: by the way your code has error you forgot the single quote. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

TO_CHAR is just a converter for the type coming out of the select query, chances are that the data can't be interrogated properly without conversion, the -1 bit (if that's also confusing you) is going to give you the day before the hire date.

Comment: so if -1 is the day before the hire date then sunday =1 monday =2 tuesday = 3 etc.  before order by will be executed it must subtract to -1  then order will be monday tuesday... sunday is that right?